# I need to write a fucntion in mySQL that returns the team with the most amount of fans

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, max

So I have a Table called "Fan" that contains the fanId, fanName and teamId. I need to count all of the the fans per teamID but the SELECT statement needs to return only the team with the largest amount of fans. I've been using the `COUNT` and `MAX` as well as `GROUP BY` but no matter what I can't seem to figure it out. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Post what you've tried, and post some sample data

Answer (score 0):

mysql does not support CTE, so it does not look good:

```
SELECT f.team_id, f.fans
FROM (SELECT team_id,COUNT(fan_id) as fans FROM fan GROUP BY team_id) f
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(fans) as max_fan
    FROM (SELECT team_id,COUNT(fan_id) as fans FROM fan GROUP BY team_id)) m
ON f.fans=m.max_fan
```